# Stata: comparing coefficients from different regressions (different dependent variables)

Tags: regression, stata

I'm doing OLS fixed effects regression, and would like to test whether coefficients are the same between the two. One of the regressions has a different dependent variable than the other.

How can I do this?

Specifically, one of my regressions is:

```
xtreg black MAshock i.year, cluster(fips)
```

The other regression is:

```
xtreg white MAshock i.year, cluster(fips)
```

Comment: This answer is plastered all over the internet. One place to look: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-05/msg00119.html, or http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-06/msg00837.html

Comment: Even more [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-02/msg00690.html), [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/chow-tests/) and [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/compreg2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

you should run one single regression and interact everything with a black dummy variable. the coefficient on that interaction term will test whether the coefficient of interest are the same or not.